# Python "isinstance" with class name instead of type

Tags: python

I want to check if an object or variable is an instance of the specified class type, but using the name of this class, not its type. Something like this:

```
class A: pass

class B(A): pass

class C(B): pass

c_inst = C()

# Not working, isinstance expects the type:
ok = isinstance(c_inst, 'A')
```

Are there any alternatives? I want to use the class name, so  `isinstance(c_inst, A)` is not available in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came up with this way, note: the class you are checking must be in globals though:

```
import inspect

def isinstance_string(variable, string):
    cls = globals().get(string, None)
    if inspect.isclass(cls):
        return isinstance(variable, cls)
    return False

class A: pass

class B(A): pass

class C(B): pass

c_inst = C()
ok = isinstance_string(c_inst, 'A')
```

Comment: What is `cls or Unused` meant to do please?

Comment: @Guimoute it was meant to replace `None` by a class that would never match. But later realized it might be problematic if `cls` was not a class so used `inspect.isclass` which made it redundant. Edited the answer and removed that.

Answer (score 4):

If you only have the class name as a string, you could do this

```py
>>> class Foo:pass
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.__class__.__name__ == 'Foo'
True
>>> foo.__class__.__name__ == 'Bar'
False
```

However this isn't very reliable, because `Foo.__class__.__name__` is writeable

```py
>>> foo.__class__.__name__ = 'Baz'
>>> foo.__class__.__name__ == 'Foo'
False
```

For superclasses, you could do something like

```
foo.__class__.__name__ == 'X' or 'X' in [c.__name__ for c in foo.__class__.__bases__]
```

though this won't pick up `object`.